# Correct way to add items to an array stored in React state with useState hook?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

I need to concat items to an array stored in React component state. I have an example on stackblitz and I cant understand why the array is not growing as i add elements using spread operator to concatenate to the existing array. Any help appreciated

link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usestate-example-ebzt6g?file=index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('React');
    const [coords, setCoords] = useState([]);

    const success = (position) => {
        // setCoords(coords.concat(position.coords))
        setCoords([
            ...coords,
            position.coords
        ])
        console.log("success! position=", position);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect -> coords =", coords);
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            success({coords : {latitude: Math.random()*51, longitude: Math.random()*2.6}});
        }, 5000);
    }, []);

    return (
    <p>example to demonstrate growing an array stored with React usestate hook</p>
    )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I think new values are added to the state but you are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). You can return the following jsx to verify it works: `<pre>{JSON.stringify(coords)}</pre>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    success({coords : {latitude: Math.random()*51, longitude: Math.random()*2.6}});
  }, 5000);
}, []);
```

The empty array as the second parameter tells react to create this effect only once, and never update it. When it's created, it has a reference to the success function in its closure, and that success function in turn has a reference to `coords`. Since this is all from the first render, `coords` is an empty array.

So every time you call `success`, you're adding the new coords to that empty array and calling setCoords. The array never grows, because your starting point is always the empty array. And you'll never see the new arrays because those only exist on later renders.

The simplest fix for this is to use the function version of setCoords. React will call the function and pass in the latest value of coords

```
const success = (position) => {
  setCoords(prevCoords => {
    return [
      ...prevCoords,
      position.coords
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I see that success becomes a stale closure because it's never re created (effect runs once). I thought only the log was logging old data.

Comment: Great explanation! Conceptually though, how does the function version of `setCoords` fix this?

Comment: @ehutchllew the problem is that the code is using a stale closure variable, so this fix changes the code so that variable is no longer needed at all. Instead, the data can be gotten through another means (specifically, the fact that React implemented setState so that it will pass in the most recent state)

Comment: @NicholasTower ah okay, that makes sense. Awesome, I appreciate the response! I'm so used to OOP, that functional paradigms like this take me a minute to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Nicholas Tower for the correct answer.

```
const success = (position) => {
  setCoords(prevCoords => {
    return [
      ...prevCoords,
      position.coords
    ]
  })
}
```

fixes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I had that problem and thanks to someone who helped me figure out how to solve that problem, first you have to clone the coords, and then u add the new coords to the clone and then you set the new clone coords to the state like this:

```
 const success = (position) => {
  let clonedCoords = [...coords];
  setCoords([...clonesCoords, position.coords]);
  console.log("success! position=", position);
};
```

this should work, if it doesn't you can reply so I can help u more

Comment: They're already making a copy of coords. That's not the problem.

Comment: he said that the list is not updating when the function success is executed, i had a similar problem and that's how i fixed it

Comment: I believe you when you say this fixed a similar problem. But it's not going to help here.

Comment: well then can you explain why ? this can be also solved by adding a function inside setCoords so it takes the old state as a parameter, but this should work the same why though

Comment: `well then can you explain why ?` Yes, you can see my full explanation in the answer i posted. But short version: the variable `coords` is always an empty array, no matter how many times this code runs. So the first time it will be fine, since you want to copy an empty array, but after that it will be no good since you want to copy the most recent array, not an empty array.

Comment: ohh i didn't see your answer, well that looks legit, thanks