# how to add a new object to an array of object in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a new object to an array of objects and want to create a in newArray variable

```
const [fruits setFruits] = useState([{name: "sam"}, {name: "jhon"}]
      
let newArray = []

const onClick = ()=>
{
     {name: "rock"}
}

result :- newArray [ {name: "sam"}, {name: "jhon"}, {name: "rock"}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to add items to an array stored in React state with useState hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273907/correct-way-to-add-items-to-an-array-stored-in-react-state-with-usestate-hook)

Answer (score 0):

Use `...` spread operator to get existing items and add new one to array.

```
setFruits([...fruits, {name: "rock"}])
```

[Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
const onClick = ()=>{
     setFruits([...fruits, {name: "rock"}])
}
```

Comment: What does this answer provide that the existing answer did not already (with more detail, I may add)?